# Split property value in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to do an `Out-GridView` to get a simple overview about our group policy objects. To do so, I am using the `Get-GPO` cmdlet, like so:

```
Get-GPO -all |
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Description |
    Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
    Out-GridView
```

In our company we use the first line of the description field to store the name of the admin who created the policy, and all following lines hold a short description.

I would want to be able to grab the first line of the the `Description` field with the column header `Responsability` and all other lines of the field in a separate column. So assuming my current code would give me a table like this:

```
DisplayName | Description
-------------------------
GPO1        | Username
            | stuff
            | stuff
```

I would want it to look like this:

```
DisplayName | Responsability | Description
------------------------------------------
GPO1        | Username       | stuff
            |                | stuff
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to use calculated properties to work with a string split on a newline from the sounds of it.

Comment: Can you show us the results but not those in Out-GridView? Those in the console mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Matt suggested, you can use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

Then since Description is a string, rather than an array of strings, you will need to split the line at the line breaks. This can be done by using `-split` and since it's information from a GPO we can assume Windows line endings `r`n (Otherwise you could use `[environment]::newline`)

The first property, use array element `[0]` will be the first line. For the second property, we'll need to save the array in a variable. Then we can use the length of that variable to get first element through the last.

```
Get-GPO -all |
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName, @{
            Name = "Responsibility"
            Expression = {($_.Description -split "`r`n")[0]}
        }, @{
            Name = "Description"
            Expression = {
                $linearray = ($_.Description -split "`r`n")
                $linearray[1..($linearray.length - 1)] | Out-String
            }
        } |
    Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
    Out-GridView
```

Alternatively, you could create a new object rather than using the calculated property.

```
Get-GPO -all |
    ForEach-Object {
        $linearray = ($_.Description -split "`r`n")
        [pscustomobject]@{
            "DisplayName" = $_.DisplayName
            "Responsibility"= $linearray[0]
            "Description" = $linearray[1..($linearray.length - 1)] | Out-String
        }
    } |
    Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
    Out-GridView
```

Comment: You could add | Out-String to keep the formatting in description 
 `$linearray[1..($linearray.length - 1)] | Out-String`

Comment: Using Out-String seems to work fine for me, since casting to string removes all line breaks

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to understand is what `Get-GPO` is returning: an array of objects, each of which has a set of properties.

What is displayed in your table is a series of rows (one per object), with the columns being the values of the properties for that object.

Therefore if you want a new column, you need a new property.

There are two ways you can do this: create a calculated property with `Select-Object` or add a property to the objects via `Add-Member`.

### Calculated

You may provide a hashtable as a property to `Select-Object`, and the hashtable must have two keys:

- `Name` (the name of the property)
- `Expression` (a scriptblock that will be executed to determine the value, where `$_` refers to the object itself)

```powershell
Get-GPO -all |
Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Description, @{
    Name = 'Responsibility'
    Expression = {
        ($_.Description -split '\r?\n')[0] # First line
    }
} |
Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
Out-GridView
```

### New Member

You can use a ScriptProperty that will execute a scriptblock each time the property is called on the object. Use `$this` to refer to the object in this context.

```
Get-GPO -all |
Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Responsibility -Value {
    ($this.Description -split '\r?\n')[0] # First line
} -Force -PassThru |
Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Responsibility, Description |
Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
Out-GridView
```

Comment: @BenH yes that's true, but the same logic can be applied to overwrite description or create a new `DisplayDescription` property or whatever. Your answer already shows solutions to that as I well (I started writing my answer before you posted, but didn't finish it until after); +1.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use something like this:

```
Get-GPO -All | ForEach-Object {
  $info = $_.Description
  $pos = $info.IndexOf([Environment]::NewLine)
  if ( $pos -gt 0 ) {
    $responsibility = $info.Substring(0,$pos)
    $description    = $info.Substring($pos + [Environment]::NewLine.Length)
  }
  else {
    $responsibility = ""
    $description    = $info
  }
  [PSCustomObject] @{
    "DisplayName"    = $_.DisplayName
    "Responsibility" = $responsibility
    "Description"    = $description
  }
}
```

This way you can preserve formatting.