# Powershell - Method to split/organize properties?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm trying to get an overview for our Active Directory users and what groups they're a part of.

Coming from a Java background, I was thinking I could just use a nested for loop to iterate through it once for the users, and another time for the groups, piping the output respectively. After testing it, I realized I had an issue where the groups would not display properly due to how the Select cmdlet formats the value. I referenced [Split property value in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530016/split-property-value-in-powershell) but I don't think it's quite what I'm looking for as there needs a way for me to recognize user-group relationship In the code below, I have 1 loop to test values.

```
 $user = @(Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select DisplayName)

     for ($i = 0; $i -le ($user.length - 1); $i += 1) {

      $group=@(Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$user[$i]'" | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Select name)

      echo $user[$i]
      echo $group[$i]
     }
```

I tested it with one user using the Identity parameter:

> $group=Get-ADUser -Identity "First Name Last Name" | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Select name

which gave me this output:

> DisplayName
>
> .....................
>
> User 1
>
> <# missing groups #>
>
> User 2
>
> User 3
>
> ...

I noticed spaces in between the Users, where the value of the group was suppose to be. I did some research into and believe that the Select-object cmdlet is the issue; I'm using Select DisplayName for users and Select name for groups but PowerShell is not able to parse both as they take up the same column so I'm assuming that to be the main issue. What I desire should appear similarly to this:

> DisplayName
>
> .....................
>
> User 1
>
> Group 1
>
> Group 2
>
> Group 3
>
> User 2
>
> Group 1
>
> Group 2
>
> Group 3
>
> User 3
>
> ...

Perhaps I've been going about this incorrectly, but is there a method to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Get-ADUser` twice is going to decrease your efficiency. Also, getting all properties when you only want DisplayName is going to decrease efficiency too. Try something like this:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName
foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $User.DisplayName
    $Groups = $User | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
    $Groups.Name
}
```

I think part of the reason you're having issues is `echo $group[$i]`. That's going to output a single group if the user even has as many group memberships as the value of `$i`.

Comment: I didn't realize you could call the properties through the dot notation. I read the Microsoft Doc on variables but it didn't give me too much insight into how the property aspect works - Do you happen to have a reference that I could read up on?

Comment: I would suggest making liberal use of Get-Help and Get-Member. I don't have a specific reference unfortunately. But PowerShell is basically object-oriented.